# How can I get Ubuntu? . I cant download it

Tags: release-management

Ever since I got my laptop, I have been wanting to explore Ubuntu. But unluckily, I can't download it because I do not have an internet connection. I have tried many times, but downloading it from cyber cafes is not possible.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: you can buy the ubuntu dvd..

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. ask someone to download the install media for you
2. ask someone to send you an install CD by post
3. ask the staff at the cyber café to download the Minimal Install version which is just around 30Mb (More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), ofcourse you will need Internet connection during the install. Perhaps you can ask them to let you plug your laptop on their network.

Answer (score 2):

You can [buy Ubuntu on DVD direct from Canonical.](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)